# What is the CSS property(if any) for the resize grip on a html form textbox?

Tags: css, textbox

I would like to be apply to apply a cursor style to the grip of the resize tool on a textbox. Currently when you hover over the box I have a `cursor: text;` property and I want to be able to change to a different cursor when hovering over the resize grip.

Here is the code, I know it doesn't matter. Just wanted it for reference.

```
<div id="form-box">
    <form action="<?php htmlspecialchars(fonefinder.php);?>" method="post" />
        <p>Enter The Number</p>
        <div class="number-box">
            <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" size="10" name="number" />
        </div>
        <h3 class="error"><?php echo $numberErr;?></h3>
        <p>Enter Your Message</p>
        <textarea name="message"></textarea>
        <h3 class="error"><?php echo $messageErr;?></h3>
        <div class="submit-btn">
            <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: According to this question's answers - you can't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932569/css-to-change-the-cursor-style-of-the-resize-button-on-a-textarea

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to style that part independently of the rest of the `textarea` (unless it happens automatically, in the browser).

Comment: I was thinking that I have seen it and I went exploring to see if I could find anything in other's css that would give me a clue. The easiest solution I could find was on here http://juiceui.com/controls/resizable Looks like a created div with a cursor property applied to it. Going to mess with it and post back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such property, but you can fake it with a little bit of JavaScript and jQuery.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9dGTR/)

```
var $textareas = $('textarea');

$textareas.on('mousemove', function (event) {
    var threshhold = 5;
    var $container = $(event.currentTarget);
    var width = $container.width();
    var height = $container.height();
    var x = event.offsetX;
    var y = event.offsetY;

    if (
        width - x <= threshhold
        && height - y <= threshhold
    ) {
        $container.addClass('resize');
    } else {
        $container.removeClass('resize');
    }
});

$textareas.on('mouseout', function (event) {
    $(event.currentTarget).removeClass('resize');
});
```

Then in your CSS, just set the cursor property based on the class:

```
.resize {
    cursor: nwse-resize;
}
```