# how to change the resize property icon and the cursor on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to change the resize icon on the corner of bottom right of the following div (see the code snippet below) , i want also to change the cursor on hover (for instance the e-resize cursor)

[image]

I tried to add :

```
#resizableDiv::-webkit-resizer {
cursor:e-resize;
background-image: url(some_image.png);
}
```

but in vain, how can i achieve that, is it possible after all ?

```css
#resizableDiv {
overflow:auto;
border:1px;
height:100px;
width:200px;
resize:horizontal;
display:inline-block;
background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="resizableDiv">
Resizable div for a single user working with Chrome
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS to change the cursor style of the resize button on a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932569/css-to-change-the-cursor-style-of-the-resize-button-on-a-textarea)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using an icon element in a separately nested element.
With a little help from a *pseudo-element* you will be able to achieve the intended behaviour, as the code snippet below demonstrates.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
#resizableDiv {
  overflow:auto;
  border:1px;
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  resize:horizontal;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:yellow;
  position: relative; /* required */
}

/* Additional */

div#resizableDiv:after {
    content: "";
    resize: horizontal;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    cursor: e-resize;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.resizeUI {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: inherit;
  padding: 0px 3px;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: e-resize;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<div id="resizableDiv">
Resizable div for a single user working with Chrome
<div class="resizeUI"><i class="fa fa-arrows-h"></i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should demonstrate with a cursor file/image, not with a browser built-in cursor, such as `e-resize` (which depends on browser).

Comment: Why not use `e-resize` when this is what OP suggests? "i want also to change the cursor on hover (for instance the e-resize cursor)"

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu why would a file image be better than using a supported style rule? Also, just had a quick look at values for the `cursor` property over at MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) and I see no reference there to browser specific rules in this regard. Can you expand on your reasoning and perhaps provide links for reference? Not only for myself, but for anyone else who might be curious.

Comment: @MehdiSouregi You presented a worthy challenge for me :)

Comment: From my understanding of the question the OP wanted to change the cursor to a custom image and be the same in all browsers (which would support the feature), rather than having a different image for resize cursor, depending on browser. Since the OP accepted your answer, I must have understood their question wrong.

Comment: I see - ok, thanks for clearing that up @AndreiGheorghiu